# How to fix ' variable in loof with innerText'

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

error in this //2 code.
Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined..

i want to crawling website .tbl_column > table > tbody > tr > td[1,2,3,4,5,6...] in loof
how to fix..?

os is mac

installed puppeteer

```
//1 - was worked well 
for(var i= 0; i< 12; i++){
      var value = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('.tbl_column > table > tbody > tr > td')[2].innerText); 
      console.log(value);
    }



//2 -  this is error syntax "i"
for(var i= 0; i< 12; i++){
      var value = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('.tbl_column > table > tbody > tr > td')[i].innerText); 
      console.log(value);
    }
```

Comment: Try using `let i= 0`

Comment: for(let i= 0; i< 12; i++){
      var value = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('.tbl_column > table > tbody > tr > td')[i].innerText); 
      console.log(value);
    } // is not working.. same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error will occur when there are less than 12 items in your `document.querySelectorAll()` result object.

Your `for` loop doesn't really make sense to me anyway.  You should be getting the result from `document.querySelectorAll()`, getting the length of the result you get and using a `for` loop based on that length value.

This also seems like something you could do some elemental debugging on by just doing a `console.log()` of the value before you do `[i].innerText` on it.

I don't know puppeteer well, but you can try this:

```
let value = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.tbl_column > table > tbody > tr > td');
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let data = items[i].innerText;
        console.log(data);
        results.push(data);
    }
    return results;
});
console.log(value);
```

Comment: 12 is testvalue. 
Actually, var courseCounts = (await page.$$('.left_line.ta_c.numbering')).length; << get length and using<< for(let i= 0; i< courseCounts; i++){
      let value = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('.tbl_column > table > tbody > tr > td')[i].innerText);
      console.log(value);
    }>> occur same error..

Comment: @Shin6 - Well, 12 is the wrong value.  You get that error when there aren't 12 items in the `querySelectorAll()` result.  That's the error you described and the code how showed.  I'm explaining why you get that error.

Comment: @Shin6 - I can't read your multiline code in comments.  Not sure what you're saying there.

Comment: thanks your code. but it was not worked too. error code is failed: ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: @Shin6 - There was a typo in my suggested code that I have now fixed (an extra paren and returning wrong variable).  Please try the current version of the code.

Comment: is not worked too. error code is disappeared but, 
There is no data on the console.

Comment: @Shin6 - Try adding the `console.log(value)` that I just added to the end of my code suggestion. It may be that the `console.log(data)` inside the `page.evaluate()` goes to a different console (the console of the page itself).

Comment: i added "console.log(value) it work well .. but how to get data in results=[]?

Comment: @Shin6 - I don't understand what you're asking?  Don't you have the data you want in the variable `value`?